# TCL write data into a YAML file

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl script that is capturing some data. I would like to write this data to a YAML file. is there any examples or places I can read about how to do this in TCL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`yaml` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/yaml.html) in Tcllib does it.

*If your data is a simple single-level dictionary,* you can just do:

```
package require yaml

set yamlText [yaml::dict2yaml $yourDictionary]
```

For example:

```
% set d {foo 123 bar "this is a piece of text"}
foo 123 bar "this is a piece of text"
% yaml::dict2yaml $d
---
foo: 123
bar: this is a piece of text

%
```

The major issue with this is that it assumes that everything in each key is really a string (though numbers are usually short enough that that comes out OK too).

Therefore, *if your data is more complex,* you need to construct a huddle description of it using the [`huddle` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/yaml/huddle.html) first. That embeds the extra type information required to generate complex structures.

```
package require huddle
package require yaml

set inner [huddle create boo "this is some text" grill "this is some other text"]
set outer [huddle create foo 123 bar $inner]
yaml::huddle2yaml $outer
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard Tcl library (tcllib) has a yaml package in it. If that package does not do what you need, you can view the source for ideas.

Comment: Thanks I looked at most of these, they seem to more focused on reading the data in from a YAML file where I am trying to write my data to a YAML file.

Comment: @bytes1234 You should look again. The package (or at least the version of it I can see) provides both.